# Extra space in the configuration details collapse the bulleted list order in the SE Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

In the Stack Exchange Android app ➡️ **About** ➡️ **Submit a bug report**, when trying to report a bug, by default the **configuration** details are showing in the body section.

[image: Extra space in the Android app]

[image: Rendered Preview of the list]

The content in the screenshot is as below (for reference of future search):

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: Motorola
- Device Model: XT1033
 - OS Version: 5.1 (2)

The four items are to be shown in the same bulleted list order, but there is one extra space before the **- OS Version:**, so it is causing the first three items to be in the same bulleted list order and the last one in the sub bulleted list.

The rendered output is below:

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: Motorola
- Device Model: XT1033

  - OS Version: 5.1 (2)

The issue is in the recent questions with the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) + [android-app](/questions/tagged/android-app) [`tags`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug+android-app).